# Populating combobox with data from a datagrid, receiving data from a sqlite database

Tags: sqlite, datagrid, air, combobox, flex3

I'm still a newbie to Adobe Air/Flex, and still fairly new with SQL.

I've downloaded this (http://coenraets.org/blog/2008/11/using-the-sqlite-database-access-api-in-air…-part-1/) code and have been looking over it and I'm trying to implement a different idea.

I'm using a canvas for this form.

MaterialForm.mxml is called by a panel CadastroMaterial.mxml which also show a datagrid with the information saved from this form.

the sql statements are made by MaterialEvent.as using the lib flexlib.

I'm having a problem getting data from a datagrid to a combobox, I'm doing this way to get the data:

```
<mx:Canvas xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" xmlns="*" width="388" height="475"     creationComplete="init()" label="{_material.material_id > 0 ? _material.tipo : 'Novo Material'}">

<mx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        import mx.controls.Alert;
        import mx.managers.PopUpManager;
        import Eventos.MaterialEvent;

        import Eventos.TMaterialEvent;
    import Formularios.TMaterialForm;
    import mx.collections.ArrayCollection;

    [Bindable] private var tMateriais:ArrayCollection;
    // Para criar a conexão com o banco de dados
    private function openDatabase():void
    {
        var file:File = File.applicationDirectory.resolvePath("bd/SISC.db");
        sqlConnection = new SQLConnection();
        sqlConnection.open(file);
        // Para verificar se o banco de dados já existe se sim utiliza-o senão cria um novo, não é útil se não cria a tabela
        //var isNewDB:Boolean = !file.exists;
        //if (isNewDB) createDatabase();

        findAll();
    }

    // Para selecionar a tabela do banco de dados desejada
    private function findAll():void
    {
        var stmt:SQLStatement = new SQLStatement();
        stmt.sqlConnection = sqlConnection;
        stmt.text = "SELECT tmaterial FROM TMATERIAL";
        stmt.execute();
        tMateriais = new ArrayCollection(stmt.getResult().data);
    }





        [Bindable] public var _material:Object;

        public var sqlConnection:SQLConnection;

        private var validators:Array;

        private function init():void
        {
            validators = [tipoValidator, responsavelValidator, compartimentoValidator];
            openDatabase();// colocado para abrir o banco de outro lugar
        }

        public function set material(material:Object):void
        {
            _material = material;
        }

        public function get material():Object
        {
            return _material;
        }

        private function save():void
        {
            if (Validator.validateAll(validators).length>0)
            {
                return;
            }

            _material.tipo = tipo.text;
            _material.num = num.text;
            _material.responsavel = responsavel.text;
            _material.compartimento = compartimento.text;
            _material.observacoes = observacoes.text;
            if (_material.material_id > 0)
            {
                update();
            }
            else
            {
                insert();
            }
        }

        private function insert():void
        {
            try 
            {
                var stmt:SQLStatement = new SQLStatement();
                stmt.sqlConnection = sqlConnection;
                stmt.text = 
                    "INSERT INTO material (tipo, num, responsavel, compartimento, observacoes) " +
                        "VALUES (:tipo, :num, :responsavel, :compartimento, :observacoes)"; 
                stmt.parameters[":tipo"] = _material.tipo; 
                stmt.parameters[":num"] = _material.num; 
                stmt.parameters[":responsavel"] = _material.responsavel; 
                stmt.parameters[":compartimento"] = _material.compartimento; 
                stmt.parameters[":observacoes"] = _material.observacoes;
                stmt.execute();
                _material.material_id = stmt.getResult().lastInsertRowID;
                label = _material.tipo;
                dispatchEvent(new MaterialEvent(MaterialEvent.CREATE, _material, true));
            }
            catch (error:SQLError)
            {
                Alert.show(error.details, "Erro");
            }
        }

        private function update():void
        {
            try
            {
                var stmt:SQLStatement = new SQLStatement();
                stmt.sqlConnection = sqlConnection;
                stmt.text = 
                    "UPDATE material set " + 
                        "tipo=:tipo, " + 
                        "num=:num, " +
                        "responsavel=:responsavel, " +
                        "compartimento=:compartimento, " +
                        "observacoes=:observacoes " +
                        "WHERE material_id=:materialId";
                stmt.parameters[":tipo"] = _material.tipo; 
                stmt.parameters[":num"] = _material.num; 
                stmt.parameters[":responsavel"] = _material.responsavel; 
                stmt.parameters[":compartimento"] = _material.compartimento; 
                stmt.parameters[":observacoes"] = _material.observacoes; 
                stmt.parameters[":materialId"] = _material.material_id; 
                stmt.execute();
                label = _material.tipo;
                dispatchEvent(new MaterialEvent(MaterialEvent.UPDATE, _material, true));
            }
            catch (error:SQLError)
            {
                Alert.show(error.details, "Error");
            }
        }

        private function deleteItem():void
        {
            try 
            {
                var stmt:SQLStatement = new SQLStatement();
                stmt.sqlConnection = sqlConnection;
                stmt.text = "DELETE FROM material WHERE material_id = :materialId";
                stmt.parameters[":materialId"] = _material.material_id; 
                stmt.execute();
                dispatchEvent(new MaterialEvent(MaterialEvent.DELETE, _material, true));
            }
            catch (error:SQLError)
            {
                Alert.show(error.details, "Erro");
            }
        }

    ]]>
</mx:Script>

<mx:Validator id="tipoValidator" required="true" source="{tipo}" property="text"/>
<mx:Validator id="responsavelValidator" required="true" source="{responsavel}" property="text"/>
<mx:Validator id="compartimentoValidator" required="true" source="{compartimento}" property="text"/>

<mx:Form width="381" height="466">
    <mx:FormItem label="Tipo:" required="true">
        <mx:ComboBox dataProvider="{tMateriais}" id="tipo" text="{_material.tipo}" width="200"/>
    </mx:FormItem>
    <mx:FormItem label="Número:">
        <mx:TextInput id="num" text="{_material.num}" width="200"/>
    </mx:FormItem>
    <mx:FormItem label="Responsavel:" required="true">
        <mx:TextInput id="responsavel" text="{_material.responsavel}" width="200"/>
    </mx:FormItem>
    <mx:FormItem label="Compartimento:" required="true">
        <mx:TextInput id="compartimento" text="{_material.compartimento}" width="200"/>
    </mx:FormItem>
    <mx:FormItem label="Observações:">
        <mx:TextInput id="observacoes" text="{_material.observacoes}" width="200"/>
    </mx:FormItem>

</mx:Form>  

<mx:Button label="Salvar" click="save()" left="16" bottom="20"/> 
<mx:Button label="Deletar" click="deleteItem()" left="87" bottom="20"/>
```

but as a result appears in the combobox [object Object] and not the name of the type of material inserted in the table TMATERIAL, if I insert 30 values ​​in Table tmaterial in another form, the 30 appear in combobox as [object Object] I traced this and the error are in this form. Could anyone help me? Sorry the english (google translator). Thnx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the `ComboBox` needs a hint as to how it should show the name for each item in the `dataProvider`. By default, many Flex components look for the elements in the `dataProvider` to have a property named `label`. If such a property exists, and it is a `String`, the `ComboBox` will display the value of that `label` property.

If the elements in the `dataProvider` don't have a `label` property, then the Flex component will call `toString()` on the `dataProvider` object which in this case results in the output "[object Object]".

If the elements in your dataProvider do not have a `label` property, then you can tell the ComboBox how to display the name by using either the [labelField](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/controls/ComboBox.html#labelField) or [labelFunction](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/controls/ComboBox.html#labelFunction) properties of the ComboBox.

Use the `labelField` property to specify the name of the property in your `dataProvider` that can be used as the label (in your case I believe this is `tipo` or `:tipo`)

```
<mx:ComboBox dataProvider="{tMateriais}" id="tipo" labelField="tipo" />
```

Or use the `labelFunction` property specify a function that will be used to generate the label for each item in the `dataProvider`.

```
<mx:ComboBox dataProvider="{tMateriais}" id="tipo" labelFunction="myLabelFunction" />
```

The `labelFunction` has the following method signature:

```
private function myLabelFunction(dataProviderItem : Object) : String
```

Comment: Sunil D. the problem continues even putting labelField = ":tipo" either labelField = "tipo" in the combobox and the function give me the error 1126: Function does not have a body if i put private function myLabelFunction(dataProviderItem : Object) : String{} give me the error 1170: function does not return a value. I am newbie and I could not quite understand what you mean and thanks for answering.

Comment: Sunil D. sorry for the answer above and thanks for answering and after much reading your post I understood and managed to solve the problem, but the label was tmaterial <mx:ComboBox dataProvider="{tMateriais}" id="tipo" text="{_material.tipo}" width="200" labelField="tmaterial"/>, thank you even for your help, you saved my application and my job.

Comment: @Maknollram glad it worked! Sorry for being unclear on the `labelFunction` method: I just gave the method signature, not a complete function. If you use the `labelFunction` you need to define a function that takes an element from the dataProvider as an argument, and using that argument the function should return a String to use as the label.